# Getting credential using GoogleAPI - HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, pythonanywhere, http-status-code-302

I get this error : 
**HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'authorize'**

I've printed HttpResponseRedirect object and I have something like this:

**HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=..."**

I've copied this url to my browser and it does work.

When I run app locally everything works fine, but now I moved my app to pythonanywhere recently and it stopped working. Here is my code:

```
def get_credentials(user):

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    home_dir = BASE_DIR + '/oauth2/' + user.username
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir, 'calendar-python-quickstart.json')
    storage = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = storage.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        print(True)
        FLOW = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES,redirect_uri="http://XXXXXX.pythonanywhere.com/accounts/google/login/callback/")
        FLOW.params['state'] = xsrfutil.generate_token(SECRET_KEY,
                                                       user)
        authorize_url = FLOW.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
    return credentials


class EventTeamToggleAPI(LoginRequiredMixin, APIView):

    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
        team = get_object_or_404(Team,slug=self.slug)
        updated = False
        added = False
        user_other_teams = Team.objects.filter(user_team_events=self.request.user).exclude(pk=team.pk)
        games = Game.objects.filter(Q(team_home=team) | Q(team_away=team))
        if self.request.user.google_cal==True:
            credentials = get_credentials(self.request.user)
            http = credentials.authorize(Http())
            service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
            {...}

        return(...)
```

Can someone explain to me what is the problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In one code path in get_credentials, you're returning a credentials object and in another code path, you're returning an HttpResponseRedirect.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Can you be more specific? The problem is that this code on server doesn't produce this google pop up window to give credentials and I get an error:

**HttpResponseRedirect' object has no attribute 'authorize'**

Locally on my computer it works fine. It stopped working when I moved that to pythonanywhere.

Comment: You have a function called `get_credentials`.   In your view you call `get_credentials`, then call `credentials.authorize(Http())`.   So if the function `get_credentials` returns an object that does not define the method `authorize`, you'll get the error you describe.    Inside `get_credentials`, you return either the `credentials` object you got from the storage, which presumably does define that method, if the credentials exist and they're valid, but if the credentials don't exist, you return an HttpResponseRedirect object, which does not define that method.

Comment: I suspect that the difference between your local machine and  PythonAnywhere is that the `if not credentials or credentials.invalid:` is true on the former, false on the latter.   Exactly why that is hard to say without knowing more about the API, but either way, the fact that you have a method that is returning different types of object depending on whether the credentials in the request are valid is something you should probably fix.

Comment: I'd suggest returning `None` from `get_credentials` instead of the redirect, then putting the code in your if statement into the view.

Comment: I understand that I get an error from authorize, because get_credentials returns object that does not define the method. But why is that? Why I can't get this pop up google login window to pass credentials ?

Comment: "get_credentials returns object that does not define the method"- that is because your code does that. your code is wrong and you need to fix it.